# No-code build - How to send a new SMS every day to subscribers

Tags: zapier, webflow

I have a webflow account, where people can signup and enter their name, email, and phone number. I want to send them a different SMS everyday, on a set schedule. What are ways you could build this with no-code tools (zapier, airtables, crm tools, etc). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The built-in "SMS by Zapier" has limitations

- Low sending rate per hour
- Restricted to certain countries

So you'll need to use an SMS sending API like Twilio.

But to be honest, using a platform like ActiveCampaign or Kartra would suit you much better.

They're built for marketing automations, and sending emails blasts.

As someone opts-in on your Webflow site, you could essentially loop them in an automation on either on those platforms e.g. "at the end, put this person back into the same automation" until they opt out.

Are you wanting to send them a SMS to try convert them, or is it like a paid service?